# Is there a way to peek into Clojure async channels without consuming their values?

Tags: clojure, core.async

I'm trying to debug something and I'd like to see what's on the channel before consuming it.

Comment: See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/QbiwXYDw6oA).

Answer (score 1):

Only for the sake of debugging, you may use something similar to function below to observe a value on a channel without actually `take!`ing it (warning: this relies heavily on `core.async` [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/103359a11598b556ac21053977e7deda43cea535/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/channels.clj#L32) [details](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/103359a11598b556ac21053977e7deda43cea535/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/buffers.clj#L16)):

```
(defn peek [ch]
  (if (and (.buf ch)
           (pos? (count (.buf ch))))
    (if (instance? clojure.core.async.impl.buffers.PromiseBuffer
                   (.buf ch))
      (a/<!! ch)
      (last (.buf (.buf ch))))
    (some-> ch .puts first second)))
```

`core.async` itself doesn't provide public API for `peek`ing value from channel.

As noted by @amalloy, the function above may fail for other kinds of buffers, in particular for those that don't have `buf` field declared.

Comment: Even if you check for `PromiseBuffer` I think you should give a stronger warning than "this relies on implementation details". The protocols core.async uses are open, so anyone could have created a new kind of channel with different internals, which won't have a `buf` field to look at.